# PHP Replace src link and keep url

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a source code like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://html.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=4.6'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://html.com/wp-content/plugins/table-of-contents-plus/front.min.js?ver=1509'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://html.com/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.7'></script>
```

How can I replace ALL the src attributes with:

"http://www.example.com/site=PLACEHOLDER&somethingelse"?
So I need to replace PLACEHOLDER with {the src website from above}

I found code snippets where I could replace the src link but not replacing it with a replaced url of itself.

How would one do that?

Comment: What did you find? Have you tried a parser?

Comment: No how would that work?

Comment: You could pull all `script` elements, then pull the `src` attribute from it, then replace it or modify it as needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the source code inside a variable you can do:

```
$code = "
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://html.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=4.6'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://html.com/wp-content/plugins/table-of-contents-plus/front.min.js?ver=1509'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://html.com/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.7'></script>";

$pattern = "/src='([^']+)/i";
$replacement = "src='http://www.example.com/site=$1&somethingelse";

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $code);
```

Comment: This looks like a perfect solution! Thank you very much!